# sort by related column in laravel lighthouse graphql

Tags: laravel, graphql, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse, graphql-php

how can I sort by related column in laravel lighthouse graphql?

For example, I have Products that have One Category but I can't SortBy Category. How can I do that?

GraphQL

```
getProducts(orderBy: _ @orderBy): [Product!]! @all

type Product {
    id: ID
    code: String
    article: String

    category: Category
}
type Category {
    id: ID
    name: String
    products: [Product]
}
```

My Models where you can see the relationship between Products and Categories

```
class Product extends Model
{
    ...
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}


class Category extends Model
{
    ...
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

---

### SOLUTION

Create a Builder

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class ProductBuilder
{
    public function getProducts(Builder $builder)
    {
        return
            $builder->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id');
    }
}
```

Then add the builder to schema.graphql

```
getProducts(orderBy: _ @orderBy): [Product!]!
    @all
    @builder(method: "App\\GraphQL\\Queries\\ProductBuilder@getProducts")
```

Now you can call and order by relationship

```
{
    getProducts(orderBy: {column: "categories.name", order: ASC}){
        id
        code
        article
        category {
            name
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If:

- Product belongs to one Category
- Category has many Products

Then Category class should look something like this:

```
class Category extends Model
{
   ....

   public function products(): HasMany
   {
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, <id_field_in_category_table>, <category_field_name_in_products_table>);
   }

}
```

And Product class should resemble this:

```
class Product extends Model
{

    ...

    public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, <category_field_name_in_products_table>, <id_field_in_category_table> );
    }

}
```

2 )Then add following to your schema.graphql.php

```
input QueryGetProductsOrderByOrderByClause {
    "The column that is used for ordering."
    column: QueryGetProductsOrderByColumn!

    "The direction that is used for ordering."
    order: SortOrder!
}

"Allowed column names for Query.posts.orderBy"
enum QueryGetProductsOrderByColumn {
    CATEGORY @enum(value: "category.name")
}

"Directions for ordering a list of records."
enum SortOrder {
    "Sort records in ascending order."
    ASC

    "Sort records in descending order."
    DESC
}
```

3. Update Product and Category:

```
type Product {
    id: ID
    code: String
    article: String

    category: Category! @belongsTo
}

type Category {
    id: ID
    name: String
    products: [Product] @hasMany
}
```

4. Update query

```
Query {
    getProducts(orderBy: _ @orderBy(columns: ["category"])): [Product!]! @all
}
```

**There was an error in my first post, it should be: @orderBy(columns: ["category"]).**

Then you should be able to query:

```
{
    getProducts(orderBy: [{ column: CATEGORY, order: ASC }]){
        id
        code
        article
        category {
            name
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach and have the next error. 
"Field \"getProducts\" argument \"orderBy\" requires type QueryGetProductsOrderByColumn, found CATEGORY."

And if I try  
Query {
    getProducts(
        orderBy: _ @orderBy(columnsEnum: "QueryGetProductsOrderByColumn")
    ): [Product!]! @all
}

enum QueryGetProductsOrderByColumn {
    CATEGORY @enum(value: "category.name")
}

Error 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category.name' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`deleted_at` is null order by `category`.`name` asc)

Comment: @Agustin I had an error in column name in the section: "4. Update query". Please check if fixing column name helps.

Comment: It's like the relation is not make when the query is executed /ERROR MESSAGE: 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`deleted_at` is null order by `category` asc)

Comment: @Agustin And after closer look it seem's that just putting CATEGORY @enum(value: "category.name") doesn't do the trick:( I'll try to find another solution because I need to implement this behavior in my own project too...

Comment: Yes, stay in contact to see how we can resolve this. Thanks for your time, points 4u

Comment: See my solution, let me know what you think

Comment: @Agustin I think your solution is the right way to do it. Works like a charm in my project too, where I'm working with movies and genres, actors and so on. Just spent a couple hours trying experimenting with a model accessors, but it didn't work either. I don't feel comfortable with the Eloquent model and try to avoid using it as long as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the query variable part is not correct. Check this:

```
{"orderBy":
    [
        {"category": 
            {"aggregate": "MAX", "column": "name"}, 
            "order": "ASC"
        },
        {"category": 
            {"aggregate": "COUNT"}, 
            "order": "ASC"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But that structure uses aggregate (numbers) to count or take the max from the collection of items from the relationship. What I need is to show and sort by (text) the only category that the product has in its relationship

Comment: What you are talking is need to be implemented by a custom builder. For such sorting one way would be to make a join between products and the category_name. This join needs to be implemented in a custom builder. The lighthouse orderBy is using laravel feature which counts without loading the model(https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models) and this type of orderBy that you need is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, @mostafa, I think so, I will let the question open, I think that this is something that more than one asks himself, maybe someone has a nice approach